# Show Some of Components in a New Window

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Say, I have a `GameObject` in my hierarchy, which has 10 components. Now, I have developed a custom inspector with a `Button` on it. I want to, by pressing the button, all of the components of the game object (or some of them for that matter, say those components which are of a specific type, or has a specific name, etc) be shown in a **new** window -let's call it the *Component Window*. Is this technically possible?

Comment: Possible? Yeah. A pain to do, since you are basically recoding the inspector? Probably.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What do you mean by "recoding"?

Comment: Well, laying out the components and listing and editing their properties is basically what the inspector does for you.